# How to let Outlook search "Sent Messages" other than "Sent Items" as default IMAP sent emails' folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, icloud, microsoft-outlook-2016

I use iCloud mail service in Outlook and I love both of them, but after a deep Google search I found my problem still not solved:

1. iCloud IMAP uses "Sent Messages" as the name of sent emails' folder, while Outlook usess "Sent Items"
2. same to iCloud - "Deleted Messages" v.s. Outlook - "Trash"
3. same to iCloud - "Junk" v.s. Outlook - "Junk E-mail"
4. the only lucky thing is that they both use "Inbox" as the name of inboxes
5. every time Outlook could not find its desired folder names (i.e., "Sent Items", "Trash", "Junk E-mail") in iCloud IMAP server, it creates folders ("Sent Items", "Trash", "Junk E-mail") in iCloud mail server, so I have dulplicate-funtion folders, which is very annoying!
6. every time I send mails in Outlook, it stores sent mails to "Sent Items" folder; every time I send mails in OS X Mail app, it stores sent mails to "Sent Messages" folder; so I have to manually merge/manage these two folders, which is also very annoying!
7. I'm using Outlook 2016 in Windows 10 so there is currently no way to use iCloud for Windows since it's not supported yet.

I tried [MFCMAPI](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) but it can only RENAME or HIDE or DELETE Outlook default folders, what I need is change the behavior Outlook search for default folders, e.g., it should search for "Sent Item" AND "Sent Messages" while adding iCloud accounts.

So my question is, is there any way or alternative app/add-in to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget it, I found the easy answer:

just use Thunderbird and NEVER use Outlook, Thunderbird full-fills my will like a charm!

Comment: Sad.  7 years later and this is *still* the best solution.